# Restore deleted user

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-accounts

I am working on SharePoint Server 2019, the IT guys messed up a user, deleted it, created a new one and after days deleted the new and restored the old one. Now in SharePoint I have all the records related to the old user, which does not exists anymore, and a new user with new ID with no records related. Is there a way to restore the old SharePoint user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the old user is restored in AD, the AD SharePoint Import service will import it to SharePoint, and you can grant it the required permission on your sharePoint site.

To ensure that the user is currently imported to SharePoint, check if it exists in the user info list at this URL:

```
SiteURL/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx
```

> Otherwise, you have to check How to [Configure profile synchronization by using SharePoint Active Directory Import in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-profile-synchronization-by-using-sharepoint-active-directory-import)

Comment: So, if the old user has really been restored, in SharePoint it has to have the old Id, right? If the SharePoint user has a new Id, it means in AD it is a new user as well?